# django rest framework hyperlinkrelatedfield for one table using its primary key

Tags: django, hyperlink, django-rest-framework

I have a table called 'users' and 'location'. Users table has a foreign key that relates to location table. I have a users serializer to get the JSON. What would I do to get the hyperlinks for the users table using its primary key?

In django rest framework documentation, I couldn't find a solution. I tried using hyperlinkrelatedfield. But still I couldn't achieve this. Can someone help me in finding the solution? I need the URL like 127.0.0.1:8000/users{userid}. It should give the JSON of the user whose userid is specified in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

- Either subclass `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`

  ```
  from rest_framework import serializers

  class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

      class Meta:
          model = MyModel
          fields = ('id', 'url', ... )  # url is the hyperlink field by default
  ```
- Or add an `HyperlinkedRelatedField` to your serializer

  ```
  from rest_framework import serializers

  class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
      url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
          read_only=True, source='pk', view_name='mymodel-detail'
      ) 
      # view name is the url pattern of mymodel detail route

      class Meta:
          model = MyModel
          fields = ('id', 'url', ... )  # url is the hyperlink field
  ```